# Using JQuery to inject an ejs template into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

Can HTML from an ejs template be injected via JQuery?

I have an `Index` file that has a navbar and a content area, as well as a sample `TestButton` template that I am trying to render.

**Index.ejs**

```
<ul>
    .
    .
    <li id="listItem"><a href="#test_page">Nav Bar Item</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="display">
</div>

<script>
    $('#listItem').click( function(){
         // Note - testButtonTemplate is being properly passed in from my routes
         $('#display').html( <%- render( testButtonTemplate, {} ) %> );
    });
</script>
```

**TestButton.ejs:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-button">
    Click Me!
</a>
```

I did my best to simplify my code, but basically, when I click on a link from the nav bar, I want to dynamically load a page in the `display` div.

---

The nav bar works.
The click functionality works.
If I manuallay display the ejs template in the div, it works.
**EX:**

```
<div id="display">
    <%- render( testButtonTemplate, {} ) %>
</div>
```

---

Otherwise, when I try to load the page with the sample code above, this is the error I get:
 "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*" and the raw html looks like:

```
.
.
<script>
$('#listItem').click( function(){
    $('#my-test').html( <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-button">
        Click Me!
    </a>
    );
});
</script>
```

So you can see that the html has been properly retrieved from the ejs template class, but JQuery does not like how I am formatting that data.  It looks like the data needs to be surrounded in quotes, but simply adding beginning and end quotes does not solve the problem.

I have tried seemingly every combination of quotes, escaped and unescaped html, storing the data in a variable first then trying to inject it, but none are working for me.

Is there an obvious mistake I'm making?  I would prefer to solve the problem given my current tool set.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your template like this:

```
<script>
var template = new EJS({url: '/TestButton.ejs'});
$('#listItem').click( function(){
     $('#display').html(template.render());
});
</script>
```